# how to populate form fields in sequence using selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to populate form fields in sequence for a test using selenium. I cannot use the name since they are assigned a unique identifer by the back end (no id).  Any thoughts on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input type="text" class="abc" tabindex="1" size="5" maxlength="15" name="8886456-98245574-3353546773" value="">
```

The same class names are being used by more than one field in the form.

Comment: List<WebElement> inputTags=driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

iterate the list and get all input tags in order.

Comment: I'll try that today and revert - thank you for sharing.  Much appreciated

Comment: any ideas on how to make it work with Selenium RC and not webdriver?  thanks for your earlier feedback - +1

Answer (score 1):

```
int inputTagCount=selenium.getXpathCount("//tr/td/input[@class='abc']");
```

The above logic will gives you count of input tags which are under tr followed by td tag

in order to find each individual input tag run the above locator in loop

```
for(int i=0;i<inputTagCount;i++}
{
     selenium.type("//tr["+i+"]/td/input[@class='abc']","test");
}
```

This is how you need to do in selenium RC